# how to update checkboxes if checked or not in mongodb database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i want to update selection boolean true or false depending on checkbox status .
how to update it on clicking on checkbox  . i made a put route in express i dont know how to get data from checkbox .this code makes 100s of ajax requests for 100 checkboxes.please help?

Schema:

```
var dataModel = new Schema({

    name:{type:String,required:true}
  ,
    email:{type:String,required:true},

    department:{type:String,required:true},

    section:{type:String,required:true},

    data1:{ type:String, required:true}
    ,
    data2:{ type:String, required:true},
    data:{ type:String, required:true},
    selection:Boolean




});
```

```
                        <% foundStudents.forEach(function(data,i){%>




                            <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <%=i+1%>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                     <%= data.name %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                            <%= data.department %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                            <%= data.section %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-primary">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">View</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="radio"  class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="selection"  value="<%=data._id%>" <%= data.selection==true ? "checked" : "" %>>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>

                        <%})%>
```

> 

---

```
    $(".btn").on('click', function () {


    var checkbox_value = "";
    $(":checkbox").each(function (i,element) {

        var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (ischecked) {
           $.ajax({
   url: '/admin/select/'+$(this).val(),
   type: 'PUT',
   data:{boolVal:true},
   success: function(response) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(url);
   }
});



        }

        else{
            $.ajax({
   url: '/admin/select/'+$(this).val(),
   type: 'PUT',
   data:{boolVal:false},
   success: function(response) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(url);
   }
});
```

node code

```
router.put("/admin/select/:id",function(req,res){
var id = req.params.id;
dataModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{ $set: { selection: req.body.boolVal } },function(err,selectedStudent){

if(err)
{
    console.log(err);
    console.log(req.body.boolVal)
}
else{
console.log("put request recieved");
console.log(req.body.boolVal)

}

})

});



router.get("/shortlistedTable",function(req,res){

dataModel.find({selection:"true"},function(err,shortlistedStudents){


res.render("./admin/shortlistedTable",{shortlistedStudents:shortlistedStudents})

});

});
```

> How to update boolean on mongoDB ? help please?

Comment: What did you try to do this?

Comment: i have another page which displays only shortlisted students so i have to update the boolean

Comment: Where is your node code ?, add it here

Comment: i have added the code thanks

Comment: You do not have `/admin/select/` route in Node

Comment: sry for the inconvenience i added code that piece of code thanks